# Using JSON & JQUERY From API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, postman

I have searched solutions for a while now and I really have tried everything. I'm new to json. New to jquery but use it frequently. I have an API that I'm trying to connect to so I need to remove the tokens.. but I'm having a major disconnect with rendering the data.

I used postman to get authorization down and using this information I get json string back. Yet when I put it on my url - nothing loads. I feel I'm missing something basic.

I want to 
- click a button
- load json data into a div - or in my example it's a table

my script is

```
         $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            async: 'true',
      crossDomain: 'true',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 
        'authorization': 'Basic OMMITTED',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache'}, 
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://www.OMMITTED.com/api/v2/orders.json?limit=200&page=1',
            data: $('#table').serialize(),
            dataType:"json", //to parse string into JSON object,
            success: function(data){ 

            if(data){
                var len = data.length;
                var txt = "";
                if(len > 0){
                    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                        if(data[i].id && data[i].customer_id){
                            txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].id+"</td><td>"+data[i].customer_id+"</td></tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    if(txt != ""){
                        $("#table").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                    }

                }
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;//suppress natural form submission
});
</script>
```

MY HTML

```
    <table id="table" class="hidden">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>customer_id</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button>Get JSON Data</button>
```

I get nothing - no errors - nothing. In another version I used

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#div1").load("TrackingResults.aspx");
        });
    });
```

with a variation of the above - and it loaded up the html into the page - but no data showed.

IF I go to POSTMAN, add the headers basic auth and token and hit the url - I get back json data

```
    [
      {
        "id": 100,
        "customer_id": 0,
        "date_created": "Thu, 07 Jul 2016 18:59:31 +0000",
        "date_modified": "Thu, 07 Jul 2016 18:59:31 +0000",
        "status_id": 0,
        "status": "Incomplete",
```

etc etc etc

The POSTMAN GENERATE CODE Produced this

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://www.OMITTED.com/api/v2/orders.json",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "authorization": "Basic OMITTED",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
     }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

This API I setup a Single Sign On token - and like I said- pasting that token and the API url into API - viola - I get data. Unfortunately I'm missing what I'm missing.

I'm looking for someone to help point me in the right direction. I've read tutorials for days, I can create text files of sample JSON data and get it to work- but no matter what I do - I can't get any of the json to create and display. Really looking for a point in the right direction as I've spend so many hours on trying to get started with json
Thanks in advance  - be easy on me. I take posting to stackoverflow seriously - you guys are awesome!

Comment: What do you get in the console if you do `console.log(data);` in the `success` function?

Comment: I get back json data formatted as expected - in my original post - the line above that says "IF I go to POSTMAN, add the headers basic auth and token and hit the url - I get back json data"

If I plugin the console.log(data); on the aspx or html or txt file - ( I tried all for kicks ) I get nothing - nor do I get errors.

Comment: Recently trying a few things - I also thought it was interesting I saved the data as a .json file, uploaded it and tried a simple ajax load and I get an erorr. It's as if json is being prevented - if that's possible

Comment: This looks like an CQRS issue